# How to move Image in Java?

Tags: java, image, swing

I am beginner to Swing and I am writing some codes. I have added images on `JLabel` and `JLabel` on `JFrame`. I want to move that Image. Is it possible to move that image(fish). If yes, How can I do it?

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

    public class Aquarium extends JFrame{

    private ImageIcon fish2image;
    private ImageIcon fish1image;
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel imglabel;
    private JLabel fish1label;
    private JLabel fish2label;
    int numberFish = 12;

    public Aquarium(){
        initComponents();
        setTitle("The Aquarium");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setBounds(500,200,500,300); //left,top,width,height      

        add(fish1label);
        add(fish2label);
        add(imglabel);

    }
    private void initComponents(){

        image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../res/aquarium.gif"));
        fish1image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../res/smallFish.gif"));
        fish2image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../res/smallFish2.gif"));
        imglabel = new JLabel(image);
        fish1label = new JLabel(fish1image);
        fish2label = new JLabel(fish2image);
        fish1label.setBounds(100,100,250,200);
        fish2label.setBounds(50,25,200,200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Aquarium();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) *"How can I do it?"* [Custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)..

Comment: Do you want to move the images by dragging them using the mouse? or you want to let them move automatically without intervention?

Comment: `setVisible(true);` This should be done after all components are added and `pack()` is called. Though don't extend frame, just use an instance of a standard frame.

Comment: Jad Chahine I want them to move automatically when the frame is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat question. But you would shift the x, and y values (Based on keyBindings or KeyListener added on frame) and it will automatically repaint.

But since you want the fist to move automatically. You are going to need either a loop based on a swing timer, Thread.sleep(1000); <= Highly not recommended, or a Thread.

Then you would shift the x and y values as described above as a certain amount of seconds pass within the method that you choose

Comment: The fishes must start to move automatically when the frame is loaded. How to do that?

Comment: All you need to do is set the location of the label and the label will repaint itself. There is no need to invoke validate(). Also, in Swing you would invoke revalidate().

Comment: Basically do the same thing and I don't know the exact difference, but revalidate() was added when Swing was designed, so I use the appropriate method for the appropriate component.

Comment: Cool. Something new. I really did not know that. Thanks